# opencart change image URL structure

Tags: php, opencart

I want to change URL structure of images in opencart. Which files must be changed? I am tried search but I can't find. I searched below folders:

```
/catalog
/catalog/controller
/catalog/model
```

Comment: your question is not clear, if you want to change the url of the images you have to change .config file in root directory, but this is one of the basics of Opencart.... If you could please rephrase your question.

Comment: I want change from: **www.mysite.com/image/cache/data/04.2014/C/aaaa/20120715120152514-80x80.png** to **cdn2.mysite.com/image/cache/data/04.2014/C/aaaa/20120715120152514-80x80.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. New OpenCart Versions Image Structure: 
**catalog/model/tool/image.php** 
*Replace this:* `return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $new_image;` 
*To This:* `return 'https://cdn1.yoursite.com/' . $new_image;` 
 
**AND**
 
*Replace this:* `return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $new_image;` 
*To This:* `return 'http://cdn1.yoursite.com/' . $new_image;`

Answer (score 0):

I will try and make this like a guide.

To change the base url of the images while keeping everything in the same way they were you simply have to go to the root of your website (where index.php can be found) there is a **config.php** file there locate it, this is the one we will edit.

From : `define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://old_domain/image/');`

To :  `define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://new_domain/image/');`

From : `define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://old_domain/image/');`

To : `define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://new_domain/image/');`

that is all you have to do and everything will work accordingly on their own.

Comment: There is no HTTPS_IMAGE on config.php

Comment: i do not know if later versions do not include this constants, if it is not  defined you can either add it manually or not add it at all, this constant is used when you use HTTPS on your shopping cart.